# I have error in"data!. documents" while connecting firestore flutter SDK version 2.5.3

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("candidate").snapshots(),
      builder: ( BuildContext context, snapshot ) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data!.documents);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: data.documents is the error   it says"he getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'"

Comment: Try `snapshot.data!.docs`.

Comment: Hi @Rajashanmugam, I have posted an answer below. Have a look at it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `documents` to `docs` should fix your error.

So in `Line 6` of your code, this:

```
return _buildList(context, snapshot.data!.documents);
```

should become:

```
return _buildList(context, snapshot.data!.docs);
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html) for more information.
Also, you may refer to this [example](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).

Comment: @Rajashanmugam Is above answer helpful?